# how to use environment setting in jade+express

Tags: css, node.js, express, pug

I am using jade with express.

In jade i want to inline css for production and link it for development mode, as shown below

> ```
> - if(environment === 'development') {
>     link(rel="stylesheet", href='styles/style.css')
> - } else {
>     style(type="text/css")                                                                                                                        
>       include ../public/styles/style.min.88b64eea.css
> - }
> ```

I am using grunt to generate compressed files(shown above style.min.88b64eea.css) in production mode. But in development mode loading uncompressed file.

It works fine if i run my server(NodeJS) in production mode, but in development mode it gives error :
**ENOENT, no such file or directory 'style.min.88b64eea.css'.**

What is wrong here? I am not sure how jade engine is handling it. Looks like it is parsing whole template file and failing for this file. If i am doing wrong, then what is the correct way of doing it?

Comment: Have you checked on the value of `environment` within the `else` block to start the debug process on why your development mode would still be calling the production file?

Comment: yes, if i remove the include statement then no error and environment comes as 'development'.

Comment: looks like i am doing something wrong. No one is using include statement with environment setting in jade file.